# Migration gerada vazia após Scaffolding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, migrations

Estou estudando ASP.NET MVC5, então criei um model chamado `RelatorioTagModels`:

```
 public class RelatorioTagModels
{
    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public decimal Tag { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Fabricante { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Modelo { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Fluido { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Vedacao { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public decimal Criticidade { get; set; }
    [Required]       
    public decimal Mtbf { get; set; }
}
```

Gerei via Scaffolding, o `Controller` e as `Views`, estou usando Entity Framework.

Porém, ao rodar o comando `Add-Migratin` ele gera um arquivo sem alterações:

```
public partial class relatorioTag : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

Minha duvida é, como que gero a tabela no banco de dados?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema não tem nada a ver com Scaffolding.

Certamente só falta adicionar o model no contexto.

No projeto deve existir uma classe que herda de `DbContext`. Esta classe deve conter todos os models referenciados.

```
public class Contexto : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RelatorioTagModels> RelatorioTagModels { get; set; }
}
```